# Extended Euclid Theorem - Can there be more than one pair of x and y for two numbers A and B

Tags: c++, math, number-theory

GCD(A,B) is Ax + By. So can there be more than one pair of x and y. If yes, how can I find them?
I used the following code to find x and y :

```
pair< int ,  int>* extendedeuclid( int a,  int b){
    if(b == 0){
        pair< int,  int>* newpair = new pair< int, int>;
        newpair->first = 1;
        newpair->second = 0;
        return newpair;
    }
    pair< int, int>* oldpair = extendedeuclid(b , a%b);
    pair< int, int>* newpair = new pair< int, int>;
    newpair->first = oldpair->second;
    newpair->second = oldpair->first - ((a/b) * oldpair->second);
    return newpair; 
}
```

When i tried to run this code for sample input a =10 , b = 9
it gives answer x = 1,y = -1 which is correct but is there any way to find other solution like x = -8 and y = 9 in this case .

Comment: this question is about maths and has nothing to do with c++ or programming in general

Comment: @user463035818: “How can I find…” is an algorithm question suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Its not up to me to decide what question is suitable for SO and which is not. I was merely refering to unrelated tags, that have been removed in the meanwhile

Comment: @user463035818: “How can I find…” with the C++ tag is a request for expressing an algorithm in C++ code. If the OP is interested in implementing the algorithm in C++, it is not an unrelated tag.

Comment: @EricPostpischil in that case it would consider it as offtopic for "asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow" or maybe some other reason. "Please write some code for me?" is not a question, is it?

Comment: @user463035818: The question does not ask for a book, tool, library, tutorial, or other off-site resource. It does ask for information. You could answer that with code, or you could answer it with information about what algorithm would solve the problem and how it could be implemented in C++.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming but rather belongs on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) once the questioner has added more of his own work and explained just where he is stuck.

Comment: @Damien: If the OP modifies the question, it gets bumped to the top of the review queue and more people will look at it. People with enough reputation can vote to reopen the question. Five votes will reopen the question, then more answers may be given. For me to vote to reopen, the OP will need to show how this is a practical programming problem. That will be difficult, since I know the answer to the question and the difficulty is all mathematical--the programming is trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This relation corresponds to the Bézout's identity.

All solutions are given by `(x + k*b/gcd(a,b), y -k*a/gcd(a,b))`, if `(x,y)` is a particular solution, where `k` is an arbitrary integer.
The particular `(x,y)` solution is for example provided by the extended Euclidian algorithm.

The pair `(b/gcd(a,b), -a/gcd(a,b))` is the 'smallest' `(u,v)` pair such that `ua + vb = 0`.

Source: Wikipedia!

Comment: @James K Polk Thank you for editing. Please note that it was a mathematical answer, not a C++ one. In my mathematics classes a very long time ago, the professor was using the term 'couple'. But it was in French, may be different in English. Anyway, as there is a 'C++' tag, better to use `pair` effectively.

Comment: Yes, I went out on a limb in my edit, in my English math classes our instructors always used the word 'pair', however if you prefer 'couple' you can revert the edit or I'll gladly do it.

Comment: @James K Polk It is assumed to be an answer in English! Better to use 'pair'. Thank you again for the correction.